# Delphi login authentication with facebook

Tags: android, facebook, delphi

I'm looking for some example code of Embarcadero Berlin for authentication through Facebook, for Android application.

My application is written in Delphi Berlin and I would like to authenticate and use facebook login. Unfortunately the demo code in the Delphi only works for Windows application.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here on docWiki you have info [about Facebook API using OAuth2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/REST_Client_Library#Accessing_Facebook_API).
Also you can see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2obh028pqrA).

To do you need use the class `TOAuth2Authenticator`. [See info here, on docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/REST.Authenticator.OAuth.TOAuth2Authenticator).

Also, TMS Software have a commercial pack [called "FMX Cloud Pack"](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxcloudpack.asp) that include components to access Facebook, Twitter, dropbox,...